# PHP: insert query result into array elements

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How can I assign query result into array elements?

This is my code:

```
include('db.php');

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Database connection error");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$query = "select * from test where value=20";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$vegetable_list = array('$rice', '$wheat', '$potato', '$pulses');
$i = 1;
while($row_result = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    ??????? = $row_result[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

How can I assign the query result into the array? Let's say:

```
$rice = $row_result[1];
$wheat = $row_result[2];
$potato = $row_result[3];
```

How I can assign the values automatically?

Comment: Wondering if this has something to do with a _farm game_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let try:

```
$vegetable_list= array('rice','wheat','potato','pulses'); //no $ symbol
while($row_result=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    foreach($vegetable_list as $k => $v)
         ${$v} = $row_result[$k + 1]; //I think mysql_fetch_row should indexing from 0 -> n (not from 1)
}
```

Comment: could u pls give me an example..because instead of retrieve result we have to assign the value of row result into the array elements.pls..help....

Comment: IT works.That's great. Exactly that's i m looking for. Thanks a lot Bang Dao..thanks--riad

Answer (score 3):

Ok not sure but seems like you have a 150column x 20rows table that you want to convert into a two dimensional array. It is as simple as this:

```
$data = array( );

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
{
    // at this point, $row contains a single row as an associative array
    // keys of this array consist of column names
    // all you need to do is append $row to $data
    $data[ ] = $row;
}

// $data is a two dimensional array
// $data[ 0 ] contains 1st row
// $data[ 1 ] contains 2nd row
// ...
// $data[ 0 ][ 'rice'  ] contains rice column value for 1st row
// $data[ 0 ][ 'wheat' ] contains wheat column value for 1st row
// ...
// $data[ 1 ][ 'rice'  ] contains rice column value for 2nd row
// $data[ 1 ][ 'wheat' ] contains wheat column value for 2nd row
// ...
// and so on

var_dump( $data );
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited the code.

Here:

```
include('db.php');
$conn=mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die("Database connection error");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

$query="select * from test where value=20";
$result=mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$vegetable_list= array( array () );
$rcols = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM test");
if (!$rcols) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo "No rows found.";
    } else {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            while ($cols = mysql_fetch_assoc($rcols);) {
                $vegetable_list[$i][$j] = $row[$cols['Field']];
            $i++;
            }
            $j++;
        }
    }
} else {
    //some error message
}
```

Comment: It's not working.I need to assign the query result value into the array elements.It's showing the parser error.on for each loop..pls give me an solution.

Comment: PROBLEM NOT SOLVED YET..dear ruel..could you please help me to solve the problem..i shall be very much glad to you..

Comment: Edited my answer, please check if its working, otherwise please post the error message.

Comment: Thanks,But it's not a feasible solution for me to write the column names.Because i write here only 4 elements .But on my real project it contents more than 150 columns.That's why i am asking for the auto value insert.Is their any other solution??Again thx for effort..pls reply if any..

Comment: I'm not referring to `$rice`, etc. What are the fields on your `test` column? If your wanted value are all in column/field named `name`, then you should write: `$row['name']`.

Comment: yes,i got your point.I have more than 150 table fields on test table.I have to insert 150 table fields value into 150 array elements..

Comment: every day 1 row.so value of last 5 years..365x5..1825 also increasing every day..

Comment: Edited again, that will take sometime for a large database.

Comment: Lot of thanks for your solution.You make a long effort for me.But Please don't think about the database.I just need to insert the query results into array declared variables.pls see the code below.It's give the first element results but not for others..why? could you pls help....$i=1;
$j=0;
$vegetable=array("rice","wheat");
while($row_result=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
     $$vegetable[$j]=$row_result[$i];
     $i++;
     $j++;     
}

echo "Rice:".$rice;
echo "<br/>";
echo "Wheat:".$wheat;

Answer (score 1):

use switch case :

```
$i=1;

while($row_result=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     switch($i) {
         case 1 : $rice = $row_result[$i]; break;
         case 2 : $wheat = $row_result[$i]; break;
     }
     $i++;
}
```

or you can do this :

```
$i=0;
$vegetable = array("rice", "wheat", "potato");
while($row_result=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     $idx = 0;
     foreach($row_result as $result){
          ${$vegetable[$i]}[$idx] = $result;
          $idx++;
     }
     $i++;
}
```

then try to

```
var_dump($rice);
```

you should get array of your specific column.

Comment: sorry it sould be mysql_fetch_assoc. i just copy paste your code. it should be work now.

Comment: Sorry brother.It's also not working.But modifying your last code it get value only for the first element.pls see my code below:                     $i=1;
$j=0;
$vegetable=array("rice","wheat");
while($row_result=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
     $$vegetable[$j]=$row_result[$i];
     $i++;
     $j++;     
}

echo "Rice:".$rice;
echo "<br/>";
echo "Wheat:".$wheat;

Comment: I think we are near to the solution.Could you pls help me to solve to retrieve all the values..

Comment: i little bit confuse, can u show me your database schema? i can't reproduce your error while i don't get enough explanation.

Comment: Thx, but error.on for each loop. Invalid argument supplied for foreach().Don't think about the database.I just need to insert the query result into array declared variables..

Comment: sorry brother again problem Invalid argument supplied for foreach()..pls help

Comment: sorry for bothering you several times.it's still not fixed mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource .Rice:Array.

Comment: yes, rice will hold your column value of database. so it must be an array. try to var_dump($rice), not to echo $rice. or do loop for every component of your column to show the result.

Comment: Hmm..i get the array value with a  Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource.but it's not fulfill my requirements.Anyway many thanks for your best effort.thx again

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that, you dont need to make array element as variable.
You can simply write without dollar sign like : $rice as rice and so on.

```
$vegetable_list= array('rice', 'wheat', 'potato', 'pulses');
```

Now execute Select query to get the data from database

```
$query = "select * from test where value=20";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

make while loop

```
 while($row_result=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
foreach($vegetable_list as $k => $v)
     ${$v} = $row_result[$k + 1]; 
   from 0 -> n (not from 1)
}
```